# Example on building a struct goes to crash

Tags: c

I'm learning structs in C and, based on my tutorial, I created this sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  //Creating a struct
  struct automobile {
         char make[150];
         char model[200];
         int cylinders;
         float horsepower;
         };
  struct automobile m_auto;  //Istantiate m_auto as automobile struct

  //Taking details as input
  printf("Car Make: ");
  scanf("%s", m_auto.make);
  printf("Model: ");
  scanf("%s", m_auto.model);
  printf("No. of cylinders: ");
  scanf("%i", m_auto.cylinders);
  printf("HP: ");
  scanf("%f", m_auto.horsepower);
  printf("--------------------------------\n");
  printf("You just entered:\n");
  printf("MAKE: %s , MODEL: %s , CYLINDERS: %i , HORSEPOWER: %2f \n", \
                 m_auto.make, m_auto.model, m_auto.cylinders, m_auto.horsepower);
}
```

I compile and everything goes ok but as soon as I run the app and input the number of cylinders the app crashes. I'm using Bloodshed Dev C++ to run, don't know if it's something wrong in my code or a compiler issue.
What's wrong?

Comment: `scanf("%i", m_auto.cylinders);` --> `scanf("%i",  &m_auto.cylinders);`, `scanf("%f", m_auto.horsepower);` --> `scanf("%f", &m_auto.horsepower);`

Answer (score 2):

You're not using scanf correctly;

`scanf("%i", &m_auto.cylinders);`

and also;

`scanf("%f", &m_auto.horsepower);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the addresses of the float and int parameters when using scanf. Currently the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Your char[] members work as they are due to pointer decay.

Didn't your compiler warn you of this? Many do these days if you set the warning level appropriately.

Comment: Zero warnings from my compiler, maybe I had to turn on warnings previously. Anyway it was tutorial's fault that didn't gave much importance to the difference between addresses of variables and (suppose) values of variables. I'll take a note of this lesson. Thank you